# android_manifest.xml is automatically changed at debug

Tags: flutter, android-manifest

I am developing a simple flutter app.
My app was working fine until I added the code
**"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"** "
into the android_manifest.xml file, as described in the related flutter documents.

here is part of my android_manifest.xml file  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myappnamehere"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" >

<uses-sdk
    ...
```

I am deleting the following line but it's added back automatically again when I run the project:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /

```
<application
    android:name="android.app.Application"
    android:appCo.....
```

I am also deleting the following line but flutter adds it back again when I run the app

```
    >>>   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <activity
     .....
```

According to the document, that permission line must be outside the application and inside the manifest block.

I don't understand why the debug action automatically adds the line back again, and to the wrong place.

Is there any idea about this?

Thank you

Comment: You have to add the permissions to the main folder's android manifest file not in debug folder

Comment: I found total 4 android_manifest.xml files at different locations (paths) under the projects. When I corrected all, the problem was resolved.